# How to goto a JPanel from a JFrame after logging into an account screen?

Tags: java

I added a login account screen and it works, still haven't corrected the buttons but it logins in fine, I did have it set to make it respond with wrong user/pass entered but I can't get that working within the code now So help with that and my current issue would be great.

My current issue is When I press submit from the login frame it use to work but I changed the menu frame to a panel and now its not showing up??

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            // This Section is for when you type the username
            // "Stacy" with the password "password" it will
            // dispose with the login window then run the 
            // menu window.

            String user=Tf.getText();
            String pwd= new String (Pf2.getPassword());
            if (user.equals("Stacy") && pwd.equals("password"))
                new Menu().setVisible(true);
            dispose(); 
        }
        });
```

If anyone can help me with adding a way to make it pop up with a JOptionDialog saying "Incorrect Username or Password".

Also the issue of making my buttons direct to JPanels from JFrames.

Thanks :)

This is a copy of my project 
[My college Assignment Project](http://www.filedropper.com/stacydb)

Comment: add an else block to your if statement, in which you show the JOptionPane message.
What exactly are the problems you have implementing what you are trying to do?

Comment: Well if you see in that code I have 'new Menu().setVisible(true);' and Menu is a JPanel. So when I run it the login works but nothing else happens.. It wont open the Menu.java class file and I am thinking cause its JPanel cause when I had it set to JFrame it was opening fine.

Answer (score 0):

> If anyone can help me with adding a way to make it pop up with a
>   JOptionDialog saying "Incorrect Username or Password".

You have to add **JOptionPane** like this

```
if (user.equals("Stacy") && pwd.equals("password"))
            new Menu().setVisible(true);
else
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
        "Incorrect Username or Password",
        ,"Error While Login"
        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

You can see the [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) for JOptionPane and other Options